# aboard: part of speech and its replacement for 'on board'

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, parts-of-speech

> Gus was aboard the president's train as it steamed out of Union
>   Station in Washington, D.C., at seven o'clock in the evening on
>   Wednesday, September 3. Wilson was dressed in a blue blazer, white
>   pants, and a straw boater. His wife, Edith, went with him, as did Cary
>   Travers Grayson, his personal physician. Also **aboard** were
>   twenty-one newspaper reporters including Rosa Hellman. 
> (Ken Follett,
>   Fall of Giants)

Bas Aarts says prepositions can be alone without their complements. And I can imagine ‘aboard’ as a preposition without complement, for there's no dictionary that calls aboard adjective. But can ‘aboard’ substitute ‘on board’ below?

Have the passengers gone *on board* yet?
-> Have the passengers gone *aboard* yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can; **aboard** is one of many English words that can be used with the same meaning as either an adverb or a preposition. In these sentences, it's an adverb (in the second, replacing the adverb prepositional phrase **on board**).